# Controller and binding async variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to control the display of elements using a variable that is defined in the controller.
But if variables change async, my code doesn't work as expected.
In my example, I output to console value of `vm.fruit` inside methods `setFruit` and `hasFruit`.
And after set value for `vm.fruit` in `setFruit`, in `hasFruit` `vm.fruit` value is `undefined`.
Have ideas about how to fix it?
And I don't want call controllers method inside directive.

UPD. I removed the definition `exampleController` from `asyncChoice`, how suggested @LeroyStav. I think he is right. But this not solved the problem.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController)
  .directive('wrapper', wrapper)
  .directive('asyncChoice', asyncChoice);

function exampleController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectMode = false;
  vm.fruit = undefined;
  vm.hasFruit = hasFruit;
  vm.selectFruit = selectFruit;
  vm.setFruit = setFruit;

  function hasFruit() {
    console.log('hasFruit: ' + vm.fruit);
    return (typeof vm.fruit !== 'undefined');
  }

  function selectFruit() {
    vm.selectMode = true;
  }

  function setFruit(fruit) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        vm.fruit = fruit;
        vm.selectMode = false;
        console.log(vm.fruit);
      },
      1000
    );
  }
}

function wrapper() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    trancslude: true,
    controller: 'exampleController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
}

function asyncChoice() {
  return {
    template: `
  <button ng-click="selectFruit({fruit: ''})"></button>
    <button ng-click="selectFruit({fruit: ''})"></button>
  `,
    scope: {
      selectFruit: '&'
    },
    controller: 'exampleController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  }
}

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper>
    <button ng-if="!vm.hasFruit()" ng-click="vm.selectFruit()">Choice fruit</button>
    <p ng-if="vm.hasFruit()">You choice <span ng-bind="vm.fruit"></span></p>
    <async-choice ng-if="vm.selectMode" select-fruit="vm.setFruit(fruit)"></async-choice>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you setting `asnyc-choice`'s controller to `exampleController`?  I've never tried something like this but my angularjs-senses are tingling... The scopes are overriding each other because you are using `vm` in both... this is frankly a mess, and I wish I had the time to help you right now but I don't.  What is clear is that you have a *severe* lack of understanding of how all of these things work and would definitely benefit from a course or a good book on the subject...  That being said, I *think* this will be fixed if you removed `controller` and `controllerAs` from `async-choice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide `$scope` to `exampleController` and call `$scope.$digest()` after execution async operation.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController)
  .directive('wrapper', wrapper)
  .directive('asyncChoice', asyncChoice);

exampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function exampleController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectMode = false;
  vm.fruit = undefined;
  vm.hasFruit = hasFruit;
  vm.selectFruit = selectFruit;
  vm.setFruit = setFruit;

  function hasFruit() {
    console.log('hasFruit: ' + vm.fruit);
    return (typeof vm.fruit !== 'undefined');
  }

  function selectFruit() {
    vm.selectMode = true;
  }

  function setFruit(fruit) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        vm.fruit = fruit;
        vm.selectMode = false;
        console.log(vm.fruit);
        $scope.$digest();
      },
      1000
    );
  }
}

function wrapper() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    trancslude: true,
    controller: 'exampleController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
}

function asyncChoice() {
  return {
    template: `
  <button ng-click="selectFruit({fruit: ''})"></button>
    <button ng-click="selectFruit({fruit: ''})"></button>
  `,
    scope: {
      selectFruit: '&'
    },
    controller: 'exampleController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  }
}

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <wrapper>
    <button ng-if="!vm.hasFruit()" ng-click="vm.selectFruit()">Choice fruit</button>
    <p ng-if="vm.hasFruit()">You choice <span ng-bind="vm.fruit"></span></p>
    <async-choice ng-if="vm.selectMode" select-fruit="vm.setFruit(fruit)"></async-choice>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```